# How to bind collection to datagrid column in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have the following model:

```
public class Order
{
 public Order()
 {
    Specifications = new List<string>();
 }
 public Guid Id { get; set; }
 public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
 public ICollection<string> Specifications { get; set; }
}

 public class Context: INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    private ObservableCollection<Order> orders;
    public ObservableCollection<Order> Orders
    {
        get { return orders; }
        set
        {
            orders = new ObservableCollection<Order>(value);

        }
    }
 }
```

I am binding the collection to datagrid in Xaml using:

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:Context/>
</Window.DataContext>
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" Name="dgUserList" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CreateDate}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

How can I add another column to bind Specifications? I tried:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
           <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Specifications}"></DataGrid>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But I am getting

> can not resolve Specifications in data context

Comment: Did you assign the `DataContext` properly?

Comment: Yes, it is assigned to a class containing ObservableCollection Orders, Id and CreateDate columns are working fine

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with ListBox:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Specifications}"></ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```