# bind list of objects with array of enum? in datagrid WPF Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, datatemplate

I wanna bind a list of objects which contain an array of enum(website?[]) in the 5th object's property, all that into a datagrid

here is my xaml code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" FontFamily="Lucida Bright" FontSize="30" LoadingRow="dataGrid_LoadingRow" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Apartment id" Binding="{Binding appartId}" FontFamily="Corbel" FontSize="23" Width="auto"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="City" Binding="{Binding place}" FontFamily="Corbel" FontSize="23" Width="auto"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding roomNb}" FontFamily="Corbel" FontSize="23" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rooms" Binding="{Binding city}" FontFamily="Corbel" FontSize="23" Width="auto"/>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Registered on">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I tried with a `datatemplatecolumn` but i don't success to bind the 5th element who is an array of nullable enum
and I wanna show in the 5th column only the elements which are != null
example:

```
       appartment id | city | adress   | rooms | websiteList
       465             paris  yello st.   4      airbnb
                                                 rental
                                                 holidaysletting
       47              tokyo  ki st.      8      rental
```

here is my code

```
 IEnumerable<BE.appartCl> ll;
    BL.Interface2 bl = BL.factoryBL.GetBL();

    public databaseP()
    {
        ll = bl.GetListApp();
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = ll;
    }
```

here is my class

```
public enum site { Airbnb, Holidaylettings, Booking, Homelidays, Homeaway, 
Sublet }
public class appartCl
{
    [XmlElement("appartId")]
    public int appartId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("place")]
    public string place { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("roomNb")]
    public int roomNb { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("city")]
    public string city { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("siteSt")]
    public site?[] siteSt = new site?[10];
    [XmlArray("recSt")]
    public string[] recSt = new string[10];
    [XmlArray("dateIn")] 
    public List<string> dateIn { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("dateOut")]
    public List<string> dateOut { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind collection to datagrid column in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48618302/how-to-bind-collection-to-datagrid-column-in-wpf)

Comment: you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119463/wpf-binding-a-list-of-a-string-to-a-column-in-data-grid as well. You just need take list control inside datatemplate.

Comment: yes but it's not a list inside the object, it's an array of nullable enum: website?[]

Comment: Share your data structure `ll` which you are binding to datagrid.

Comment: thanks you for your help :)
i added data structure